# Magento 1. Copy all product attribute Labels and Options from storeview 1 to storeview 2

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute, multistore

So we have created a new store. Only to see that wee have to manually OPEN and COPY all product attributes Labels and Options 1 by 1. Storeview X already has the correct Labels and Options.

**Question**: Is there a method to copy ALL product attributes Labels and Options from a certain storeview and store them to the new storeview?

- Loop over product attributes
- Get value from root storeview = X
- Copy to storeview = Y

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere I have a PHP script for this, but I could not find it actually ... (will update later ...hopefully)

Something we used in the past ...

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function(){
    var bodyClass = $('html-body').classNames().toString();
    if (bodyClass == 'adminhtml-catalog-product-attribute-edit') {
        var map = {
            2: 3,       //DE
            1: 17,      //EN
            10: 18,     //FR
            11: 19,     //IT
            12: 20      //ES
        }

        var re = /option\[value\]\[(\d+)\]\[\d+\]/; 

        $H(map).each(function(pair){
            var sourceLabel = $$('input[name="frontend_label[' + pair.key + ']"]')[0];
            var targetLabel = $$('input[name="frontend_label[' + pair.value + ']"]')[0];
            if (targetLabel.readAttribute('value') != sourceLabel.readAttribute('value')) {
                targetLabel.setAttribute('value', sourceLabel.readAttribute('value'));
                targetLabel.setStyle({backgroundColor: 'lightgreen'});
            }

            $$('input[name^="option[value]"][name$="[' + pair.key + ']"]').each(function(s){
                var sourceClass = s.readAttribute('name');
                var matches;
                if ((matches = re.exec(sourceClass)) !== null) {
                    if (matches.index === re.lastIndex) {
                        re.lastIndex++;
                    }
                    var sourceOption = s.readAttribute('value');
                    var targetOption = $$('input[name="option[value][' + matches[1] + '][' + pair.value + ']')[0];
                    if (targetOption.readAttribute('value') != sourceOption) {
                        targetOption.setAttribute('value', sourceOption);
                        targetOption.setStyle({backgroundColor: 'lightgreen'});
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

You have to add this script to attribute edit page and adjust store IDs in `var map`. Not nice, but it works if you save your attributes manually...

Comment: Great!! Would be good also if m2 has something for this. I also have a working script for the label (not the options) and will post when behind laptop

Comment: It has always surprised me that there is no option to do this language based. Of course maybe you want to override on a storeview level. But often for the same language you use the same values.

Comment: @snh_nl if it is "great" there is a button ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this sql query, just change your attribute ID and store id's.

```
UPDATE eav_attribute_option_value as t1
    INNER JOIN eav_attribute_option_value as t2
        ON t1.option_id = t2.option_id AND t2.store_id = 2
    SET t1.value = t2.value 
    WHERE t1.store_id = 4 AND t1.option_id IN (
    SELECT option_id FROM eav_attribute_option WHERE attribute_id = 235
    )
```